# How can it be possible to localize a ring at a set with zero divisors?

Tags: commutative-algebra, localization

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity, and $S$ a multiplicative subset of $R$ not containing $0$. Which step in my reasoning is wrong?

1. Every element of $S$ is a unit in $S^{-1}R$.
2. Every element of $S$ that's a zero divisor in $R$ is a zero divisor in $S^{-1}R$.
3. But zero divisors can't be units. Therefore it's not possible to localize $R$ at $S$.

Comment: For such a subset you get $S^{-1}R = \{0\}$, so 1,2,3 are true. Simply you get $1=0$ in your ring :)

Comment: @N.H. Maybe I'm misunderstanding you, but according to Wikipedia, $S^{-1}R=\{0\}$ if and only if $0\in S$.

Comment: You are right I am sorry, I did answer too quickly.

Comment: The only related thing in [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_(algebra)) that I found says that $R\to S^{-1}R$ is injective if and only if $S$ does not contain any zero divisors.

Comment: Ok let me try a second time. Assume you have $as = 0$ with $a \in A$ and $s \in S$. In the localization, $(a,1) \sim (as,s) \sim (0,1)$. Thus $a = 0$ and $s$ is not a zero divisors anymore in $S^{-1}A$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I'm sorry, I was talking about [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_of_a_ring#Properties) article.

Comment: Oh! Sorry, Jack. I should have guessed that there might be several WP articles on this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider the localization of $R=\Bbb{Z}_6$ with respect to the multiplicative set $S=\{1,3\}$. In $S^{-1}R$ we have $2/1=0/1$ because $3\cdot(2\cdot1-0\cdot1)=0$. It follows soon that $S^{-1}R\simeq \Bbb{Z}_2$. You see that $3/1=1$ is invertible in that ring.

The error is that even if an element $a\in R$ is a zero divisor in $R$, it may happen that $a/1$ is not a zero divisor. This is because it may happen that for all $b\in R$ such that $ab=0$ we get $b/1=0$ in $S^{-1}R$.

Comment: My mental model this whole time was that $S^{-1}R$ is the simplest extension of $R$ in which every element of $S$ is a unit. But in fact, $S^{-1}R$ might not even be an extension of $R$.

Comment: Yeah, this kind of a localization is a bit non-intuitive. I had to think about it for a while. I guess algebraic geometers meet such beasts daily :-)

Comment: Although, the inclusion $R\to S^{-1}R$ has kernel $\{a\in R\mid \exists s\in S,\ as = 0\}$, so localizing at a set $S$ with zero divisors in it can be thought of as a two-stage process of first quotienting out zero divisors, and then taking the "minimal extension" approach I mentioned above.

Answer (score 6):

Step 2. is false:
Consider $R=\mathbb R[X,Y]/(X\cdot Y)=\mathbb R[x,y]$ and $S=\{1,x,x^2,x^3,\cdots\}$.
We have $S^{-1}R\cong \mathbb R[x,\frac 1x]$. The element  $x\in R$, which was a zero-divisor in $R$  (since $xy=0,\; y\neq 0$), is no longer  a zero-divisor in $S^{-1}R$ (since that last ring is a domain).