# Do multplicatively closed subsets of a ring contains a zero-divisor?

Tags: ring-theory, modules

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with $1$ and $S$ be a multiplicatively closed subset of $A$. Can $S$ contain zero-divisors of $A$ and still we get $S^{-1}A \ne \{0\}$?

My confusion is in the following point:

For all $s \in S \ ; \ \frac s1$ is a unit in $S^{-1}A$. Also if $a \in A$ is a zero divisor then $\frac a1$ is a zero divisor in $S^{-1}A$.

So if $S$ contains a zero divisor $a$ then $\frac a1$ is both a unit and a zero divisor which is a **contradiction**.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You mean to say that I proved it by the method of contradiction?

Comment: Being a unit and a zero divisor is not a contradiction, it just means that the ring is $\{0\}$ because that's the only ring in which the multiplicative identity is $0$.  Unless, of course, you also said "suppose the localization isn't $\{0\}$."

Comment: @DonThousand Let $e$ be a nontrivial idempotent in a commutative ring and $S=\{1,e\}$.  $e$ is a zero divisor, but are you sure $RS^{-1}=\{0\}$?  I think the multiplicative set actually has to contain zero, right?

Comment: NO, if $S$ contains zero divisors then then $S^{-1}A$ can still be non-zero, if $S$ contains zero divisors, this just means that the localization map is not injective. For example $x$ is a zero divisor in $\Bbb Q[x,y]/(xy)$ but the localization at $\{1,x,x^2,\dots\}$ is $\Bbb Q[x]_x$ non-zero.

Comment: The problem is that the element $a$ annihilating $s$ in $A$ (i.e. $as=0$) will become zero in $S^{-1}A$ so $s$ might not be a zero divisor in $S^{-1}A$

Comment: @leoli1 it would be nice i you would provide a solution in the solution section. Thanks!

Comment: @leoli:  if the fraction ring is nonzero. Can we avoid the contradiction I provided in my question?

Comment: See my last comment and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2151299/how-can-it-be-possible-to-localize-a-ring-at-a-set-with-zero-divisors?rq=1)