# If $S$ contains a zero divisor, then $S^{-1}R$ is the zero ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, localization

I have $R$ a commutative ring with neutral element and $S$ a multiplicative subset. I also have $S^{-1}R=\{\frac{r}{s}, r\in R,s\in S\}$.

> I have to prove that if $S$ contains a zero divisor, then $S^{-1}R$ is the zero ring and I also have to say for which Ideals $I$, $S=R\setminus I$ is closed under multiplication.

Regarding the statement I don't know if the following proof is okay: Let $x\in S$ be a zero divisor. This means that there exists $y\ne 0$ such that $xy=0 \in S$ since $S$ is closed under multiplication. And when $0\in S $ we know that $S^{-1}R$ is the zero ring (we had a proof of that in the lecture).

And could also somebody help me with the ideals, which ones make $S=R\setminus I$ closed under multiplication?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: $S^{-1}R=0$ iff $0\in S$ ($R$ commutative with unity).

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg It seems to me that user26857's statement is correct: $S^{-1} R = 0$ if and only if $1_{S^{-1} R} = 0_{S^{-1} R}$, i.e. $\frac{1}{1} = \frac{0}{1}$, if and only if there exists $s \in S$ such that $s(1\cdot 1 - 1\cdot 0) = 0$.

Comment: Sorry I had to delete my wrong comments.

Comment: The assertion that the localization is zero if $S$ contains a zero divisor is incorrect. See the [comments here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4064143/29335) and the solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2151299/29335)

Answer (score 1):

These are exactly the prime ideals. You probably defined a prime ideal as an ideal $P$ where $xy\in P$ implies either $x\in P$ or $y\in P$. It is straightforward that the statement "$x,y\in R\setminus P$ implies $xy\in R\setminus P$" is an equivalent definition.

Comment: Thank you, what about my proof? Was it okay?

Comment: @Annalisa Was just about to write about it. $x\in R$ being a zero divisor means that there is some $y\ne 0$ such that $xy=0$. I assume in your question you mean that there is some zero divisor $x\in S$ for which the corresponding $y$ also belongs to $S$. In this case your proof is correct. But if $y\notin S$ then in general $S^{-1}R$ is not necessary the zero ring. For example, take $R=\mathbb{Z_6}$ and $S=\{1,3,5\}$. Then $S$ contains the zero divisor $3$, but it does not contain the zero element. Fact is, $S^{-1}R$ is trivial if and only if $0\in S$.

Comment: And in this case $0 \in S$ only if $y \in S$?. Would it make any difference if it is said also that $S$ has the neutral Element.

Comment: Well, yes. My example shows that if $S$ just contains a zero divisor then $S^{-1}R$ might not be trivial. However, if $xy=0$ for some $x,y$ which both belong to $S$ then indeed $0\in S$.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that
$$ S^{-1}R = (S\times R)/{\sim}$$
where
$$ (s_1,r_1)\sim(s_2,r_2)\iff \exists s\in S\colon ss_1r_2=ss_2r_1,\tag1$$
which - writing $\frac rs$ for the equivalence class of $(s,r)$ - allows us to define desired ring operations in the usual way as $\frac ab\cdot\frac cd=\frac{ac}{bd} $ and $\frac ab+\frac cd=\frac{ad+bc}{bd}$, using $(1)$ to show that these operations are well-defined.

Now consider the case $R=\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z$ and $S=\{\,(1,n)\mid n\in\Bbb Z\,\}$. Note that $S$ contains the zero divisor $(1,0)$, but $S^{-1}R$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$ because $(1)$ readily turns into $(s_1,r_1)\sim(s_2,r_2)\iff r_1=r_2$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does this mean that the statement is not always true?